# Unable to get any other values other than CID and LAC using RIL WM6

Tags: window, windows-mobile, ril

Unable to get any other values other than CID and LAC using RIL WM6 using 
GetCellTowerInfo, any info is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the implementation for your specific Windows Mobile device the RILCELLTOWERINFO structure may not be fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

Which phone-network were you using?

You will find that Mcc and Mnc are only present on GSM Devices.